# Shell script IF condition equality check not working for string returned from function

Tags: bash, shell

So I am facing a rather annoying problem.
I have two files:
`check_ongoing_deployment.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

check_ongoing_deployment() {
  deploy_status=$(get_deploy_state "node-server")
  echo "${deploy_status}"
}
```

`main.sh`

```
source "$(dirname "$0")/check_ongoing_deployment.sh"
    deployment_status=$(check_ongoing_deployment)
    echo "Deployment status: $deployment_status"
    if [[ ${deployment_status} == "PRIMARY" ]]; then
      echo "No deployment in progress for ${service_to_wait}."
    else
      echo "Deployment on going for ${service_to_wait}. Waiting for deployment to complete."
    fi
```

The problem is the `IF` condition in `main.sh` is not working.
The `echo` shows `deployment_status` is in fact `"PRIMARY"`, but its not getting equated to the string `"PRIMARY"`.

However, when I change `check_ongoing_deployment.sh` to just return a string like:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash
    
    check_ongoing_deployment() {
      deploy_status=$(get_deploy_state "node-server")

      # echoing String
      echo "PRIMARY"
    }
```

The `if` condition in `main.sh` is working.

So it looks like it has something to with the getting the returned value from the function, but I cannot figure out what the `if` condition is missing, as the returned value seems identical string.

EDIT:
I have tried the following and still having the issue:

```
deployment_status=$(check_ongoing_deployment)
status=$(echo $deployment_status | tr -d '\r')
#status=$(echo $deployment_status | sed -i 's/\r$//')

if [[ $status == "PRIMARY" ]]; then
```

PS:
Why are people is such a hurry to close questions? Did you check the script yourself and confirmed that it is indeed a duplicate and the solution works? This is more annoying than the issue.

Comment: `echo -n "$deployment_status" | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"'`?

Comment: @Darkman Thank you. This is the `hexdump`: `225052494D41525922`

Comment: `echo -e '\x22\x50\x52\x49\x4D\x41\x52\x59\x22'` gives you `"PRIMARY"`. See? there are double quotes in that variable, but you only check it without the quotes. Thus `'"PRIMARY"'` is the one you're looking for.

Comment: @Darkman Thank you so much for taking the time to find the issue. After removing the double quotes it worked. Thanks for saving my day.

Comment: While the duplicate is apparently incorrect, we don't reopen unclear or unreproducible questions. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: I was not the user who closed your question. (Also, neither I nor the closer is a moderator on this site.) Who's hurrying to conclusions here?